# Ember Javascript framework

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to bind a click event for a DOM element through ember. I have created Application,Model and Controller and used handle bar template in the HTML page.

I parsed the JSON and loaded data's into the view but i don't know how to bind click event to the DOM elements using ember framework.

Comment: Can you post a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) with what you have done?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `{{action}}` helper, for example:

```
<button {{action buttonWasClicked}}>Click Me</button>
```

Then add a buttonWasClicked method to your controller.

See http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/